# data-ng-options directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following AngularJS controller code:

```
  $scope.orders = Order.query()
  $scope.order_statuses = OrderStatus.query()
```

Each order has 'order_status_id' field.

And the view (HTML SLIM):

```
    table.table
        tr ng-repeat="order in orders | orderBy:'-id'"
            td.col-xs-6.vertical-align
                | Order \#{{ order.id }}
            td.col-xs-6
                select data-ng-options="o.title for o in order_statuses" data-ng-model="order.order_status_id"
```

As you can see I draw all orders in table, and each order has select with order statuses. Each select has all order statuses, it works. But I bind status of each order in 'data-ng-model' attribute, but it doesn't work - each select is unselect. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to place a option that contains the instruction for the user:

```
select data-ng-options="o.title for o in order_statuses" data-ng-model="order.order_status_id"
   option selected=selected "Please select the matching orderstatus"
```

I don't know the current syntax in html slim. The text is the node description.